# Initial Value Problem to find series solution

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence, initial-value-problems

> Consider the following initial value problem:
> $$e^{-x}y'' + \ln(1 + x)y' - x^2y = 0$$
> $$y(0) = 1$$
> $$y'(0) = 2$$
>
> 1. (done) Show that $x = 0$ is an ordinary point in the differential equation.
> 2. Find the first $4$ non-zero terms of the series solution centered in $x = 0$;
> 3. Which is the radius of convergence of the series solution found in $(2)$?

I have solved number 1, but number 2 seems to be giving me way too much trouble. First, I can't find the series solutions. I feel like I'm missing some quick corners, as I may not need to spend one full hour trying to work out the math in this. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Three questions in one, all homework. Good luck!

Comment: @qfwfq It's a math problem.

Comment: Math homework, sure, I didn't claim it was homework in social studies or some such.

Comment: You will probably get better feedback if you show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @Gregory thanks, Gregory. I have gone a little further. I always try to avoid speaking too much, because it usually scares people from even reading. SO is actually just as bad with feedback for newcomers, usually, so thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer specifically addresses one way to work through part (2).

Assuming a solution of the form

$$y=\sum_{n\ge0}a_nx^n=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots$$

notice that $y(0)=a_0=1$, and similarly you have $y'(0)=a_1=2$.

Differentiate twice to find

$$y'=\sum_{n\ge0}na_nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n\ge1}na_nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n\ge0}(n+1)a_{n+1}x^n\\
y''=\sum_{n\ge1}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}=\sum_{n\ge2}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}=\sum_{n\ge0}(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^n$$

Recall that

$$e^{-x}=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-x)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}x^n\\
\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-x)^n}n=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-1)^n}nx^n$$

Now in the ODE replace everything you can with these series expansions:

$$e^{-x}y''+\ln(1+x)y'-x^2y=0$$

becomes

$$\left(\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}x^n\right)\left(\sum_{n\ge0}(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^n\right)+\left(\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-1)^n}nx^n\right)\left(\sum_{n\ge0}(n+1)a_{n+1}x^n\right)-\sum_{n\ge0}a_nx^{n+2}=0$$

Simplifying this looks like a sordid business, but fortunately the exercises asks you for just first several non-zero terms of the series expansion of $y$. To that end, we only care about extracting what information we can about the first several $a_n$, so consider truncating the expansions up to, say, $4$ terms each:

$$\color{red}{\left(1-x+\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}6\right)\left(2\cdot1a_2+3\cdot2a_3x+4\cdot3a_4x^2+5\cdot4a_5x^3\right)}\\
\quad\quad+\color{green}{\left(x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4\right)\left(a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+4a_4x^3\right)}\\
\quad\quad-\color{blue}{\left(a_0x^2+a_1x^3+a_2x^4+a_3x^5\right)}=0$$

Expand the left side and collect terms with the same power of $x$:

$$\begin{array}{c|rl}
x^0&\color{red}{2a_2}+\color{green}{0}-\color{blue}{0}&=0\\
x^1&\color{red}{(-2a_2+6a_3)}+\color{green}{a_1}-\color{blue}{0}&=0\\
x^2&\color{red}{(a_2-6a_3+12a_4)}+\color{green}{\left(-\frac{a_1}2+2a_2\right)}-\color{blue}{a_0}&=0\\
x^3&\color{red}{\left(-\frac{a_2}3+3a_3-12a_4+20a_5\right)}+\color{green}{\left(\frac{a_1}3-a_2+3a_3\right)}-\color{blue}{a_1}&=0
\end{array}$$

Now, with $a_0=1$ and $a_1=2$, compute the next few coefficients:

$$\begin{align}
2a_2=0\implies a_2&=0\\
a_1-2a_2-6a_3=0\implies a_3&=-\frac13\\
-a_0-\frac{a_1}2+3a_2-6a_3+12a_4=0\implies a_4&=0\\
-\frac{2a_1}3-\frac{4a_2}3+6a_3-12a_4+20a_5=0\implies a_5&=-\frac16
\end{align}$$

So we find

$$y(x)\approx1+2x+\color{lightgray}{0x^2}-\frac{x^3}3+\color{lightgray}{0x^4}-\frac{x^5}6$$

Comment: This is honestly very beautiful and clear... (and it was a bit hard for me to see) Thank you!

Comment: Looking at it now, a0 + 2 a2 = 0, thus a2 = -1/2. which would also chage the value of a3. Is that right?

Comment: Not quite. I noticed I've made a mistake with the contributions of the $-x^2y$ term, which has no constant or linear terms in its expansion. I've fixed this.